# Selecting & editing 2nd Excel graph object in Word document with C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm having an issue selecting & editing a 2nd Excel graph object in a Word document.

I have a C# application, developed in Visual Studio 2010.  Earlier I have the code:

```
// Excel objects.
Word.InlineShape pieShape = wrdDoc.InlineShapes[1];
if (pieShape.OLEFormat.ProgID == "Excel.Chart.8")
{
    // Ensure object is running.
    object verb = Word.WdOLEVerb.wdOLEVerbHide;
    pieShape.OLEFormat.DoVerb(verb);

    xlPieWrkBk = (Excel._Workbook)pieShape.OLEFormat.Object;
    xlPieDataWrkSht = xlPieWrkBk.Worksheets["DX"];  // 'DX' is the name of the data worksheet for the displayed pie graph.
}
```

and is successfully able to update **xlPieDataWorkSht** which updates the pie graph.

However, I have a 2nd graph later in the same Word document.

Code

```
Word.InlineShape pieShape = wrdDoc.InlineShapes[2];
```

Doesn't work. In fact **wrdDoc.InlineShapes** only appears to have one object.
How do I access the 2nd graph in the document.

**or**

Is it possible to have both graphs use the same set of data instead of updating 2 separate worksheets of data?

Comment: **Resolved**: The 2nd graph wasn't an 'inline' object, the format was floating. Once I changed the formatting it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd graph wasn't an 'inline' object, the format was floating. Once I changed the formatting it's working fine